# What is the difference between \includegraphics and \includegraphics*?

Tags: graphics

I don't understand the description on page two of the `graphicx` [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/graphics/graphicx.pdf):

> The star form is just for compatibility with the standard interface,
>   and essentially just adds `clip` to the keys specified.

1. What is the *standard interface*?
2. Means *adds `clip`* following `\includegraphics[clip]{}` is the same as `\includegraphics*{}`?

Thank you for your help and effort in advance!

Comment: You can load `graphics` and `graphicx`. The former has a different interface (referred to as standard interface here) from the latter.

Comment: Hello Skillmon and @David Carlisle. Thank you for your comments! I now understand the difference. Moderators counld now decide what is to do with my question. Possibilities:
**1.** Mark as duplicate.
**2.** Close.
**3.** Answer.